# How do I listen for children visibility change?

Tags: java, layout, swt, visibility

I'd like to resize a control when its internal layout is changed. The change is caused by ExpandableComposite which toggles visibility of it's children.

Is there a way to recursively hook every child in hierarchy and listen for its visibility change?

Following works if applied after the last child is attached:

```java
IExpansionListener listener = new IExpansionListener() {
    public void expansionStateChanging(ExpansionEvent e) {
    }
    public void expansionStateChanged(ExpansionEvent e) {
        Point min = compositeContainer.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT);
        compositeContainer.setSize(min);
    }
};
void recursivelyAddListener(Control control, IExpansionListener listener) {
    if (control instanceof ExpandableComposite) {
        ((ExpandableComposite) control).addExpansionListener(listener);
    }
    if (control instanceof Composite) {
        for (Control child : ((Composite) control).getChildren()) {
            recursivelyAddListener(child, listener);
        }
    }
}
```

How to support child additions on later stages?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support for such a change in SWT. I'd try to encapsulate your `setVisible(boolean)` calls and call listeners, too.